# How can I mimic a table's fluid cell width but still allow line wrapping?

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to do this without JavaScript. I already have a JS solution but want to know if this is possible with pure CSS.

Let's say you have a page showing products off. When the page resizes I want to have those product boxes flex with the page layout. Each one should have a max-width and min-width. A table won't work because I can't have a fixed number of columns. Depending on the browser width, there could be between 1 to 6 products on a single row. The following doesn't work, but it's the closest I've got.

```
#prducts > div {
    float: left;
    max-width: 200px;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    background-color: #3333FF;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/79CBq/2/

Is it possible to make a DIV do auto width and still adhere to the min/max values I set? Unfortunately width: auto only changes the width if there is content inside making it bigger.

This is just really dumb to me, because a DIV with "display: block" has the right kind of auto-width but I can't find an option to give that to an inline-block or float DIV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a grid-system. 
For your information: you can set the width of your divs in percentage (based on the width of the parent container).

If you want all `<div>` elements in `#prducts` to be 1/6 of the screen width, you should remove the width of `prducts` (set it to `auto`) and then do this:

```
#prducts > div {
   width: 16.666%;
}
```

Beside the typo in #products you should know that you are using the id identifier. You can only have one html element width the id "products". If you plan to have more then one, you should change that to a class name.
I don't really unterstand what you want to do in your fiddle. You should not use tables for layout reasons. With my anweser and your fiddle, you will run into problems width the margin of the `> div` items, which you could easily avoid using a box based layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap grid system, bootstrap takes care of the media queries. You need to give the div classes such as "col-md- " depending on the columnwidth and the screens you want to support. If you do not want to use the full library you could mimic bootstrap implementation for fluidic layouts. 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/